# Are there good Star Wars game resources?

Tags: tools, star-wars-saga-edition

I'm working on a Star Wars Saga Edition game, and I was wandering if anyone has any good encounter or adventure sized resources? Particularly, I am looking for interesting locations (such as a droid factory, a jedi temple, etc.), good SciFi Tilesets for use with programs such as Maptool, and well made creatures outside the books.

Anything you guys can point me towards to make my game easier or more interesting? I've already figured out how to easily make an Opening Crawl, using [this](http://www.gesteves.com/experiments/starwars.html) page's source code and a screen capture program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me, SW GMing always starts with cool locations, so I'll start there.

A good starting point for maps is the Star Wars minis gamer community, which (inevitably) produced a lot.  Some are a bit cramped or busy, as they were designed for tactical interest in a skirmish wargame, but in a lot of cases that only makes them work better for RP.

Some links:

- The [Holocron](http://the-holocron.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=36&func=select&id=1) is probably the biggest SWM map archive.

  - Includes a reasonable [Jedi Temple interior](http://www.the-holocron.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=36&func=fileinfo&id=38).
  - There's a usable (if somewhat generic) [Droid Factory](http://www.the-holocron.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=36&func=fileinfo&id=163).
  - I also quite like the useful [Salvage Yard](http://www.the-holocron.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=36&func=fileinfo&id=28).
- [StarWarsMaps](http://starwarsmaps.blogspot.com/)
- [Chris West's Star Wars maps](http://www.mapsofmastery.com/scifi.html)

For tiles, I'm quite fond of TileSystem, an editor originally written to handle maps for FFGs Doom.  The tileset style isn't perfect for SW, but the Doom and Space Hulk tilesets are good for rapidly sketching starship/space station maps.  (I prefer pyMapper, but nobody's adapted any good SF tilesets for that yet that I know of.)

- [Tilesystem](http://members.cox.net/shawnriordan/tilesystem.htm)
- [Space Hulk Tileset](http://www.warseer.com/forums/showthread.php?t=217976)

There's an archive of NPCs, droids and creatures for Saga here:

- [Saga Edition](http://saga-edition.com/)

Also, my favorite tool for starting SW games with a bang: the word processor.  For SW I always borrowed the old West End Games trick of starting the adventure in media res, with a short script for the players to set the scene.  It suits the genre, and gets things moving immediately.  (I prefer to take a tip from Lucas, back when he had a decent editor... Star Destroyer full of troops boarding a corvette *first*, slow down and establish plot *second*.)

Comment: This post will cause me to waste endless hours sucking up more useless star wars trivia and errata... I am in your debt.

Comment: No debt.  Researching this post has caused *me* to waste hours... mostly printing and assembling more maps.  So it's even.

Comment: Despite liking the in media res starts, I always found the scripts clumsy and limiting - there was always some bit of dialog that in no way suited what any of the characters would actually do or say.

Comment: Very true, @YogoZuno - I never used the WEG scripts as-is without editing to match the characters.  But that's what GMs are for ;)  The idea was better than the execution - so I used the idea and did my own execution, writing my scripts as called for by the adventure and PCs present.

Comment: Honestly, I always found it better to just do away with the scripts, and present the situation as I would in any other game. Let the players come up with the weird stuff in the game, not have it thrust upon them.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Tynam's great suggestions (some of which I'll be checking out tonight)...

Look up the Dawn of Defiance adventures.  Wizards of the Coast did a complete 10 adventure story arc that will take a party of 4 to 6 characters from level 1 to level 20.  You won't find them on the WotC site anymore because they don't have the Star Wars license but there are web sites that have the complete archive.  You can also look up stand alone adventures like Betrayal of Darth Revan (one I'm about to take my players through).

One great resource is the D20Radio SW:SE forums.  You can find them [here](http://d20radio.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=47).
There's even an [adventure specific](http://d20radio.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=6) forum where GMs post stuff. In there you will find posts listing links to adventures like [this one](http://d20radio.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=62966#p62966).

While you're there should subscribe to the [Order66 podcast](http://start.d20radio.com/home/the-order-66-podcast) (it's free).  GM Chris and GM Dave do a fantastic job of guiding GMs in creating and running SW:SE games.